How to access postgresql via pgsql in python
I installed pysql via
pip install pgsql

Now I writed code follow the example on https://pypi.org/project/pgsql/
import pgsql

with pgsql.Connection(("localhost", 5432), "postgres", "password") as db:
    report_items = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM "declare_report"')
    print(len(report_items))
    report_items.close()

And I got the error like below:
pgsql.Error: relation "declare_report" does not exist (42P01)

And I'm sure the table has been created, and I can read and insert in pgadmin.
I also try
SELECT * FROM "public.declare_report"

The error is same. How to fix it?
ps: I just need a client to do crud, I try psycopg2, but it seemed I must install postgresql before psycopy2 installation. Is there any light postgresql clients on python3.9?
My os is windows 11 and python3.9

Your connection string lacks the exact database name and in this case it will use the database "postgres". The same name as the username, "postgres" in this case. Usually you won't create tables and other objects in this database, but you create your own database first. So what is the name of your database?

Offtopic: Don't use the double quotes " about object names in your database, they will cause a huge amount of bugs. It's very unlikely that you have a table with this name: "public.declare_report". If you do, in what schema did you create this table? public? public."public.declare_report"...


You  don't need to install Postgres to use psycopg2, you can install psycopg2-binary which includes all the necessary files. See psycopg2 INSTALLATION. 2) This SELECT * FROM "public.declare_report" should be either ... public.declare_report or ..."public"."declare_report". 3) Have you actually created the table declare_report?


Use psycopg2 instead of pgsql
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=host,
    dbname=dbname,
    user=user,
    password=password
)

